# jQuery injection with squarespace 6

Tags: jquery, code-injection, squarespace

I'm helping a friend customize their squarespace 6 site, but jquery doesn't seem to be working correctly.

We have a box that when clicked, it will open a lightbox asking for email sign up. They would like it to open automatically when you visit the site. (see below).

```
<div class="sqs-block-content">
<span class="lightbox-handle">Join the Mailing List</span>
<div class="form-wrapper hidden">
<div class="form-title">Mailing List</div>
<div class="form-inner-wrapper">
```

Then in the head injection area, I added the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(window).load(function() {   
            setTimeout(function(){ $(".lightbox-handle").click(); }, 1000);
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with JQuery, i don't think squarespace uses JQuery so they havent imported it to the solution.

This could work if you use the code injection:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```